# error CS0019: Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal' in c# console app

Tags: c#, console-application

I tried to compile the solution multiple times. But it is not compiling when i am using double as variable type. The code is:

```
using System;
class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool Flag=true;
        string action = "Null";
        double priceGain=0;
        Console.WriteLine("press 'q' or write \"quit\" to exit the application");
        while(Flag==true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the price Gain? ");
            string input=Console.ReadLine();
            if(double.TryParse(input,out priceGain))
            {
                if (priceGain <= 2m)
                {
                    action ="Sell";
                }
                else if(priceGain > 2m && priceGain <= 3m)
                {
                    action="Do Nothing";
                }
                else
                {
                    action="Buy";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(action);
            }
            else if (input.ToLower()=="q" || input.ToLower() =="quit")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input! please enter a number");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The error I am getting while compiling is :

> error CS0019: Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'
>   error CS0019: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'
>   error CS0019: Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'

**But when i am using int or decimal instead of double as variable type the progam is compiling and working fine**.

Comment: The error message says exactly what is wrong. Double cannot be compared with decimal. So compare it with something else, like another double.

Comment: Not that obvious if you don't know the shorthands `m`, `d`, `ul`, etc. @RaymondChen

Comment: @PatrickHofman well the m suffix was in the original program so I'm assuming they know what it means seeing as they wrote it.

Comment: Actually i am not very used to of using shorthands. So I am practicing a example program with various ways and didn't recognise **m**.

Comment: Instead of `while (flag == true)`, just use `while (flag)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That is better. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2m` is a `decimal` since the `m` is short for decimal. You can use `d` if you want a double.

```
if (priceGain <= 2d)
```

`decimal` and `int` can be compared without casting, but not double, as you have experienced.

Note that you might suffer from the imprecision of floating point numbers, so if you can, use decimals.

Comment: You: _`decimal` and `int` can be compared without casting, but not `double`_ More precisely, a `decimal` and an `int` can be compared, and in the same way a `double` and an `int` can be compared. But this is really because there is an ___implicit___ conversion from `int` to `decimal` and also from `int` to `double`. So this is really a comparison of two `decimal`, respectively two `double`, after the implicit conversion of the right-hand side. So `decimal` and `double` are "symmetric" in this regard, and they cannot be compared to each other directly.

Answer (score 1):

`M` denotes a `decimal` literal. For double, just use e.g. `2` (or better, `2d`) instead of `2M`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the double to decimal and it should work, like this:

```
using System;
class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool Flag = true;
        string action = "Null";
        decimal priceGain = 0M;
        Console.WriteLine("press 'q' or write \"quit\" to exit the application");
        while (Flag == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the price Gain? ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (decimal.TryParse(input, out priceGain))
            {
                if (priceGain <= 2m)
                {
                    action = "Sell";
                }
                else if (priceGain > 2m && priceGain <= 3m)
                {
                    action = "Do Nothing";
                }
                else
                {
                    action = "Buy";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(action);
            }
            else if (input.ToLower() == "q" || input.ToLower() == "quit")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input! please enter a number");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```